# Issues with Input Stream in Java during testing

Tags: java, testing, stream

I'm testing my program against a test database, and to conduct these tests, I need to input data, which I do using System.setIn. However, only the first test runs correctly; all subsequent tests fail due to the error java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found. I've attempted to revert to the standard System.in using **mark()** and **reset()**, but it didn't help.

```java
public class UserProfileInteractionTest {
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        assertTrue(DataBaseOperations.openDBConectionTest());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void registerRegisteredProfileTest(){
        String input = "Test test test\ntest@gmail.com\ntestpassword\n";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        User user = new User();
        UserProfileInteraction register = new UserProfileInteraction(user);
        assertFalse(register.registerAccount());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void loginRegisteredProfileTest(){
        String input = "test@gmail.com\ntestpassword\n";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        User user = new User();
        UserProfileInteraction register = new UserProfileInteraction(user);
        assertTrue(register.loginAccount());
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        assertTrue(DataBaseOperations.closeDBConection());
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods `mark()` and `reset()` will not "restore the standard System.in". The only way to do that is to assign the original reference of `System.in` elsewhere for safekeeping (e.g. in a `@BeforeClass` method), and revert back to it after each test (e.g. in an `@After` method). As an aside, the fact you need to reassign `System.in` for your test to work points out that your code is probably too tightly coupled to `System.in`, and that you may want to come up with another design.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to restore the original standard input stream (System.in) after each test case is executed. You can achieve this by using a @After method to reset System.in back to its original state.

In this modified version:

- We introduce a tearDown() method annotated with @After that resets System.in to its original state (originalSystemIn) after each test case is executed.
- We store the original System.in stream in a field called originalSystemIn during the setUp() method.
- @AfterClass method closeConnection() remains to ensure proper closure of database connection after all tests are executed.

  public class UserProfileInteractionTest {

  ```
   private static InputStream originalSystemIn;

   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUp() {
       assertTrue(DataBaseOperations.openDBConectionTest());
       originalSystemIn = System.in;
   }

   @Test
   public void registerRegisteredProfileTest(){
       String input = "Test test test\ntest@gmail.com\ntestpassword\n";
       InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
       System.setIn(in);
       User user = new User();
       UserProfileInteraction register = new UserProfileInteraction(user);
       assertFalse(register.registerAccount());
   }

   @Test
   public void loginRegisteredProfileTest(){
       String input = "test@gmail.com\ntestpassword\n";
       InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
       System.setIn(in);
       User user = new User();
       UserProfileInteraction register = new UserProfileInteraction(user);
       assertTrue(register.loginAccount());
   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() {
       System.setIn(originalSystemIn); // Reset System.in to its original state
   }

   @AfterClass
   public static void closeConnection() {
       assertTrue(DataBaseOperations.closeDBConection());
   }
  ```

  }